# Suppose $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $m_{*}(A) = 0$, then show that $m_{*}(A \times R^m) = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $m_{*}(A) = 0$, then show that $m_{*}(A \times R^m) = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$.

The result seems intuitive, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

$m_{*}(A) = 0$ implies that for every $\epsilon$, there exists a rectangle $R$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $R$ covers $A$ and $m(R) < \epsilon$. Then $R \times \mathbb{R}^m$ covers $A \times \mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $m(R \times \mathbb{R}^m) \leq \epsilon * \infty = \infty$ .

I know that $0 * \infty = 0$, but how do I get to that point when every $\epsilon$ only gets me to $\infty$?

edit: I realize it doesn't mean there's a single rectangle that covers $A$, but a sequence of rectangles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B_k$ be the box around the origin in $\mathbb{R}^m$ each of whose sides is of length 2k. Write
$$
A\times \mathbb{R}^m = \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A\times B_k
$$
Then, 
$$
m_{\ast}(A\times \mathbb{R}^m) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} m_{\ast}(A\times B_k)
$$
So it suffices to prove that $m(A\times B_k) = 0$ for all $k$. Now apply your argument with $A\times B_k$ instead of $A\times \mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: Hi, so how are you allowed to take the lim from inside the $m_{*}$ to the outside without using continuity from below (since we can't use it here since we're dealing with outer measure)?

Comment: If $m_{\ast}(A) = 0$, then $A$ is measurable

Comment: Yes but we do not know that $A \times B_k$ is measurable in this problem.

Comment: But we do! $A$ and $B_k$ are both measurable in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ respectively!

Comment: In this problem we can't assume that the cartesian product of measurable sets is measurable in $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ because this is one part of proving that exact statement.

Comment: Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: Right, okay, thanks.